# Hide a Column function doesn't work

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to hide a column with google spreadsheet, here is what I have tried:

```
var form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(form.getDestinationId());
var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
sheet.hideColumn(8);
```

However, I get this error:

> Cannot find method hideColumn(number). (line 50, file "Registration")

If I let IntelliSense do its work, it shows me that the method exists. What exactly am I doing wrong here?

Note: I would like to rull out any null references, because commands like the following work without a problem:

```
sheet.setColumnWidth(1, 130);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hideColumn excepts Range and not an integer value. If you want to pass a column number then use hideColumn**s**. Hope this helps.

```
  var form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(form.getDestinationId());
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
  sheet.hideColumns(8);
```